# setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH using tomcat's setenv.sh script

Tags: java, linux, tomcat

I can't seem to get tomcat to properly set environment variables.  I can run my .jar normally with my LD_LIBRARY_PATH set to the correct place, it finds my external libraries just fine.  If I unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH and run the jar I get the error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Native code library failed to load: 
  ensure the appropriate library (opl<VERSION>.dll/.so) is in your path.
```

which is to be expected.

Anyway, I created a tomcat/bin/setenv.sh script that looks like this:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/public/lib
```

But when I run my code over the webservice I still get the same error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Native code library failed to load: 
  ensure the appropriate library (opl<VERSION>.dll/.so) is in your path.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Is what you are missing.

and also perhaps an appropriate addition of `-Djava.library.path=MYDIR` to the java flags.

Comment: Darn, neither of those seemed to help... I also tried copying all my libraries to /usr/share/tomcat6/lib and /lib that didn't seem to work either

Comment: That certainly won't help. Run with debug turned on and post the messages you see. You are putting the containing dir of the shared libs in those two places?

Comment: Are you sure that it's reading setenv.sh at all? Toss an echo command in there.

Comment: To expand: if you do `foo=bar` inside of `setenv.sh`, then the setting of `foo` is only valid for the exection of `setenv.sh` itself. Once this shell script is done, `foo` no longer exists. `export foo=bar` makes the variable `foo` (and it's value of `bar`) available to the parent shells/environments.

Comment: @bmargulies - I'm not sure how to turn debug on in tomcat.. And yes I'm sure setenv.sh is running I threw a echo "\n\n\n TEST \n\n\n" in to see.

Comment: @matt b - Yes I know, this is why I figured I'de give export a try, but all of the setenv.sh examples don't actually use export.  probably because they are called from the tomcat startup script and only local variables settings are actually needed

Comment: to be clear: I have Tomcat servers in which my `setenv.sh` has lines like `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=foo` and `export JAVA_OPTS=bar`, and it works as I expect. It needs to be `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=somevalue` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=somevalue; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH`; not solely `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as the answer might lead you to believe.